# Search query using GET API in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I am using version 7.4.
I wanna achieve mainly three things.
I want to filter as per a date range and then search for a keyword in the "title" field and output selected field. Below is the code I tried but not working, Please help.

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "multi_match": {
          "query": "Market",
          "fields": [
            "title",
            "message"
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "range": {
          "published": {
            "gte": "now-300d/d",
            "lt": "now/d"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "title",
    "message",
    "published"
  ]
}
```

I am getting as below

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
        "line": 3,
        "col": 17
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "no [query] registered for [filtered]",
    "line": 3,
    "col": 17
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

Is there any other way or any correction in the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ES 7.4** not support **filtered** instead of that we will use **must** query

```
POST <index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "Market",
            "fields": [
              "title",
              "message"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "published": {
              "gte": "now-300d/d",
              "lt": "now/d"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "_source": [
    "title",
    "message",
    "published"
  ]
}
```